# Spring Data REST filtering data based on the user

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

If I have a repository setup like the following, making use of Spring Data REST, I can access the data at /receipts and see all data.  However, I want to only return data for the user.  I have a custom finder "findByStorer" which would do this.  How would I get Spring Data REST to use this and get the storer value from the user rather than specifying a query parameter?

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "receipts", path = "receipts")
public interface ReceiptRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Receipt, BigDecimal> {

    @Query
    public Page<Receipt> findByStorer(String storer, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I haven't implemented any security yet, so this question is more theory at the moment than practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Building on @rpr's answer:

You should be able to reference properties of the joined entity (Storer). In your example if you have Receipt -> Storer -> User you can query the Receipts where Storer.user has a value injected from the Security Context.

```
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated && (#userName==principal.username)")
Page<Receipt> findByStorer_User(@Param("userName") String userName)
```

Comment: How can we make this findByStorer_User() method be the default, replacing the findAll() when a user with limited access uses the API? We want to keep the findAll() for admin users, and have a limited method for restricted users.

Answer (score 3):

For example, given a `Repository`for `SomeEntity` you could override `findAll` method with a custom `@Query` filtering by attribute `owner`with value of`#{principal.username}

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "some-entities", collectionResourceRel = "some-entities", itemResourceRel = "some-entity")
interface SomeEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SomeEntity, String> {
  @Override
  @RestResource(exported = true)
  @Query("select someEntity from SomeEntity someEntity where someEntity.owner = ?#{principal.username}")
  Iterable<SomeResource> findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Spring Security you can use this approach:

```
@PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated() && (#userName == principal.username)")
public List<User> findByUserName(@Param("userName")String userName);
```

Comment: this doesn't quite explain how to go from the username to the storer, if for example to join the Receipt table to User table you need to go through the Storer table. IE, something like `select * from user, receipt where user.storer = receipt.storer`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a tipical cross-cutting concern so I tried apply AOP. Define Advice and update the args (String storer), as explain at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46353783/1203628

```
@Aspect
@Transactional
@Component
public class FilterProjectsAspect {

@Pointcut("execution(*  com.xxx.ReceiptRepository.findByStorer(..))")
    public void projectFindAll() {
    }

    @Around("projectFindAll()")
    public Object  filterProjectsByUser(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

        Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] instanceof String) {
                String storer=(String) args[i];
                // Find storer by user 
                args[i]=storer;  //Update args
            }
        return pjp.proceed(args);
    }

}
```