# Spring boot REST service with multiple users

Tags: rest, jpa, spring-boot, multi-tenant

First of all, I spent some time thinking whether this question belongs to SO, so if you think it is more appropriate for some other Stack Exchange site, please feel free to recommend or migrate.

I am writing a REST application which will be able to register new users and allow the existing users to interact with each other (you can imagine a forum or a minimalistic social network, for example).

At the moment, I have a simple app setup with database schema, **spring-JPA** and **spring-data-rest** exposing all the repositories.

However, all users are now able to access all the resources from the server. I would like a user to see only his own entities: for example by going to `/api/user/messages`.

I am also going to use some security in the application, probably OAuth2, so I need it to be compatible.

I have read some articles and SO questions concerning this topic and decided that **multi-tenancy** might be a solution to my problem. Usually though, these articles work with separate databases for each client and smaller number of clients in total so I am curious whether it is actually meant to be used for a huge number of users in the system. I expect all the users to share the database with their records and use the same schema.

Is there some tutorial for this topic concerning spring boot and shared database-schema? Or is there some better approach how to solve this problem? I would be glad for any tips!

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, using multi-tenancy might be an overkill for this task, since I only need to separate the users on entity level. I would be glad for any hint how to do that in Spring boot and JPA since I have found no tutorials concerning this topic.

Comment: You don't need multitenancy for that, you just add a condition for the current user in your database queries, which are executed when calling these REST endpoints.

Comment: @dunni You are probably right, I updated my answer. I am still struggling how to implement such thing, though

Comment: See if this link helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640487/spring-data-rest-filtering-data-based-on-the-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't many explanations on how to achieve what you've described even though it would seem to be a common problem.  Hopefully the Spring team will address this very common use case.  The following is what I've seen as two possible solutions, the second of which is what I use.

**Complex Solution**:

### [Spring Security ACL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls)

**Simple Solution**:

### [@Query Method Security Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#data-query)

Example:

```
@Query("select m from Message m where m.user like ?#{hasRole('ADMIN') ? '%' : authentication.name}")
```

`@Query` methods are typically used to define more complex queries than can't easily be written in the method-name query creation that is a standard mechanism of [Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation).

You can add Security logic within a `@Query` method that can return different results based on who the User is.

The above example will return all Messages if the User has a Role of ADMIN, but if not it will return only their own Messages.  This has the added benefit of Query optimization.  You could select all the records and then programmatically filter out those that the User doesn't have access to, but for large queries this becomes a bottleneck.  This will adjust the query at runtime based on who is requesting the data.  I've found it to be the best way to achieve the desired behavior without implementing a full ACL.

Comment: Thanks you. I quite liked the approach suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834138/spring-data-rest-return-resources-of-user -> @PreAuthorize("isFullyAuthenticated && (#userName==principal.username)")  since I don't like hard-coding any SQL queries in the code. I am also planning to use some security (probably OAuth2) so I need it to be fully compatible.

Comment: @Smajl I referenced that option in my answer but indicated it has significant downsides as you need to programmatically process the results as opposed to dynamically adjusting your query which results in dramatically improved response times, especially for complex schemas.  See this comment on the link you provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834138/spring-data-rest-return-resources-of-user#comment49810007_30877376

Comment: You are right, I will give it a try and see if it works for me.