# Spring Boot REST: Filter results depending on user role

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am building a rest backend with authentication and different roles. Now the problem is, that I like to filter, the result depending on the user role.

I don't have implemented the controller myself, instead, I am using the 
`PagingAndSortingRepository Inferface`, this is working pretty well. What I am looking for is something similar to this `python-django` [method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods).

The solution must conform to the REST pattern.

To make this clearer, here is an **example**:

Let’s say I have two users, user A is a normal user with the role "user". User B is an admin with the role "admin".

There is a Database table, in which the `userData` are stored. The table looks like the following.

```
| ID | username | name | email |
```

Both of them are sending a simple **authenticated** `GET` request to `/userData`.

Now my backend detects based on the `authentication` header the users and add the roles.

Now depending on the role, the user A should only get an answer which contains his personal data, user B should get all data which are accessible through `/userData`.

Response for user A:

```
{
   "res":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "username":"userA",
         "name":"A",
         "email":"userA@mail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Response for user B:

```
{
   "res":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "username":"userA",
         "name":"A",
         "email":"userA@mail.com"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "username":"userB",
         "name":"B",
         "email":"userB@mail.com"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "username":"userC",
         "name":"C",
         "email":"userC@mail.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: So the controller queries a service for querying the data? And you pass the authentification to that service?

Comment: No, i don't have a controller. The methods for `GET`, `POST` etc. are created runtime by spring boot, throught the `PagingAndSortingRepository Inferface`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data REST filtering data based on the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640487/spring-data-rest-filtering-data-based-on-the-user)

Comment: As you can see in the possible duplicate, it's far easier to have two separate endpoints and to secure on of them using the `@PreAuthorize` annotations.

Comment: That is true, but this is not conform to the rest pattern. I think that would be a quite dirty solution. Especially because I would have to secure a ton of endpoints like that.

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension for Spring-Data-Jpa which can handle these kind of requirements (+ a lot more).
[spring-data-jpa-acl](https://github.com/BerryCloud/spring-data-jpa-acl/tree/master/acl)

You can set up rules by roles or associations with a few simple annotations and all of the data-jpa methods and REST endpoints will be affected by these rules.
The extension adds extra specifications to JPA queries so all filtering will happen in the DB side, so you can even use pagination on filtered data.